# Filter pixel based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, colorfilter

I have a piece of code as bellow:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import operator
from functools import reduce

image = cv2.imread("<some image path>")
bgr   = np.int16(image)

h, w, _ = image.shape
mask    = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

# Get all channels
blue  = bgr[:,:,0]
green = bgr[:,:,1]
red   = bgr[:,:,2]

rules = np.where(reduce(operator.and_, [(red > 100), (red > green), (red > blue)]

# Create mask using above rules
mask[rules] = 255

### Then use cv2.findContours ...
```

This piece of code doesn't run enough fast as I expected. I think I can make it more faster by apply all conditions one by one, ie:

```
rule_1 = np.where(red > 100)
rule_2 = np.where(red[rule_1] > green)
rule_3 = np.where(red[rule_2] > blue)

mask[rule_3] = 255
```

Can the above method speed up my code? And how to do that? Many thanks!

Comment: How about `mask[red > 100 & red > green & red > blue] = 255`? Or better: `mask = (red > 100 & red > green & red > blue) * 255`. `np.where` is usually unnecessary and a waste of time.

Comment: `bgr   = np.int16(image)` -- what's that hoping to achieve?

Comment: @DanMašek cv2 read image into uint8 format. If not convert to int16, my filter doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great way is (adapted from Cris Luengo's comment)

```py
mask = 255 * ((red > 100) & (red > green) & (red > blue))
```

but if you need faster, you can use [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)

```py
from numba import jit, prange

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True) 
def red_dominates(rgb, mask):
    M, N, _ = rgb.shape
    for i in prange(M):
        for j in prange(N):
            r = rgb[i,j,0]
            g = rgb[i,j,1]
            b = rgb[i,j,2]
            mask[i,j] = 255 * ((r > 100) & (r > g) & (r > b))
    return mask
```

Notice that `prange` is used instead of `range`. This tells Numba that the loops are parallelizable.

On my computer the Numba version is about 3x faster.

```py
>>> bgr = np.int16(255 * np.random.random((100, 100, 3)))
>>> w = np.ones(bgr.shape[:2], np.uint8)
>>> %timeit red_dominates(bgr, w)
13.7 µs ± 26.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>> %timeit 255 * ((bgr[:,:,0] > 100) & (bgr[:,:,0] > bgr[:,:,1]) & (bgr[:,:,0] > bgr[:,:,2]))
46.3 µs ± 208 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Note that **OpenCV** uses BGR ordering rather than RGB, so your function would need to be called with `red_dominates(image[...,::-1], mask)`. Also, note that the speed gains are more impressive with larger images, try 1920x1080.

Comment: Many thank for opening my mind! This the first time I try numba, can you explain why in the first time numba take long time to run? Maybe this time used to compile python code?

Comment: Yes, that's correct - it compiles on the first call.